# why 18.04 mini.iso install boots into a terminal window?

Tags: 18.04

First install of this 32 bit mini.iso version, was expecting the "normal" desktop I have on 16.04 on another machine which I think is Gnome, but got the terminal which I can not exit with "exit", ctl D, etc, Chose Vanilla Gnome during install. Maybe can change desktop from the term?

Comment: 18.04 32bit mini.iso is only 57MB. It is too small to include a DE.

Comment: Selected Ubuntu desktop during install and expected that would be downloaded rather than included in the .iso. If that occurred ok, maybe the solution is to simply enable it, somehow